# Prime ideal not containing $r\in R$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Suppose $R$ is an integral domain and $r\in R$. I am trying to prove that there is a prime ideal of $R$ that does not contain $r$, but am having trouble figuring out how to proceed.

If $r$ is nonzero, then we can take the ideal $\{0\}$, which is prime since $R$ has no zero divisors.

So suppose that $r=0$. But every ideal contains $0$. What am I missing?

Comment: What you say is true, and every (prime) ideal will contain zero.  So check that you read the exercise correctly.

Comment: I did, so maybe the exercise as stated is incorrect.

Comment: What about assuming $r \ne 0$?

Comment: If $r\neq 0$ then the $0$ ideal works, I believe.